# Match a string that does not end with a list of known strings

Tags: python, regex

I want to match street names, which could come in forms of " St/Ave/Road". The postfix may not be exist at all, so it may just be "1st". I also want to know what the postfix is. What is a suitable regex for it? I tried:

```
(.+)(\s+(St|Ave|Road))?
```

But it seems like the first group greedily matches the entire string. I tried a look back (`?<!`), but couldn't get it to work properly, as it kept on spewing errors like "`look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`".

If it matters at all, I'm using Python.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make your first group non-greedy by adding a question mark:

```
(.+?)(\s+(St|Ave|Road))?
```

Comment: Beat my a few seconds so you win.

Comment: TIL. That is pretty sweet that one more character solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to regex-based solutions, how about:

```
suffix = s.split(' ')[-1]
if suffix in ('St', 'Ave', 'Road'):
  print 'suffix is', suffix
else:
  print 'no suffix'
```

If you do have to use regular expressions, simply make the first match non-greedy, like to: `r'.*?\s+(St|Ave|Road)$'`

```
In [28]: print re.match(r'(.*?)\s+(St|Ave|Road)$', 'Main Road')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x260ead0>

In [29]: print re.match(r'(.*?)\s+(St|Ave|Road)$', 'nothing here')
None
```

Comment: Removed my answer in favour of this. Python's built-in string methods are much more readable than regular expressions and easier to maintain.

Comment: I may have multi-word suffixes, like North East. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You wanted negative look ahead

```
(?!(St|Ave|Road))$
```

Answer (score 0):

How about negative look behind:

```
(?!<=(St|Ave|Road))$
```

it seems to express the requirement closely

Comment: The idea is good, but there are two problems: First, this regex is incorrect - in its current form it means "assert that it's not possible to match the characters `<=`, followed by `St`, `Ave` or `Road` right at the end of the string". The correct form would have been `(?<!St|Ave|Road)$`. Second, Python doesn't support variable-length lookbehind in its current `re` module.